# Delphi export to Excel (.xlsx)

Tags: delphi, xlsx, xls

When export to xls there is no error when export to xlsx there is error into cell " the number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe" but there is no apostrophe

[image]

why strange behavior happening?

Update: 
I using QExport4XLS, QExport4Xlsx, kbmMemTable - datasource.

```
MemTable.FieldDefs.Add('Price', db.ftFloat, 0, False)
...
MemTable.FieldByName('Price').AsFloat := Value
...
QExport4X*.DataSet := MemTable;
...
QExport4X*.Execute;
```

Comment: Which version of the `QExport4*` components? What is the setting in your `Excel` regarding decimal separator? Is the text *... but there is no apostrophe* really part of the error message, or is it your comment to the error message?

Comment: QExport4XLS seems to be from sqlmanager.net.  What do its publishers say about the problem?

Comment: sorry it was my comment

Comment: QExport4 version 4. I not yet to inform them

Comment: I suspect it's QExportXlsx bug. Looks like passing string value instead of float

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I using v4.0 so it was component problem as according their bug fix tracker after v4.2 they did fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because in both cases (xls and xlsx) you are exporting the values as string. The recent version of Excel, show you that it thinks the cell's value could be of another type by showing you the upper left green triangle.
You should check the type while exporting.

Whitout seeing the code is obviously a wild guess.